# In CakePHP Auth - is there a way to force https on all actions requiring Authentication (but not others)

Tags: php, cakephp, https, authentication

Using CakePHP Auth, I want to have all actions that require being logged in to also be forced to use https.

Is this possible via a callback somehow?

Further info: I have admin routing in use as well as certain "member-only" actions.
Using CakePHP 1.2 also.

Many thanks for any pointers on this.

Answer (score 2):

New for version 2.x:
SecurityComponent::requireSecure()
see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

Answer (score 0):

The login page must also be served over HTTPS, and you probably want a `secure` session cookie for logged in users, so it isn't transmitted when accessing the site over HTTP (this means that the user won't appear as logged in when browsing over HTTP).

Comment: I was going to secure the login page - thats a help with the cookei part though, I will attend to that too, thanks.

Comment: If the cookie is secure, then the user can't be logged in over HTTP (unless they explicitly edit the cookie, or they have a browser that doesn't support it).